# Linux I/O Redirection

Tags: linux, bash, io, redirect

This query saves Standard Out and Standard Error to same file (out):

**find /home -not -group root > ~/out 2>&1**

How can I combine contents of both streams alphabetically and save to a file?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Pass them to `sort`.

```
find /home -not -group root > >(sort > ~/out) 2>&1
```

Comment: Which is a bashism. To stay portable, use `... 2>&1 | sort > out`

Comment: Thank you
Also this work,as Jo So claims:
find /home -not -group root 2>&1 | sort > out

Thank you